# How to reset docker preferences on MAC

Tags: macos, docker, apple-m1

I'm using Docker Desktop for M1 MAC and I was playing around with allocating different amount of resources and I have somehow ended up breaking the application. Docker Desktop is constantly stopping/starting, I cannot open preferences as I only get the spinner and cannot proceed.

I have reinstalled the app multiple times, tried all deletion scripts I could find online, deleted all Docker related files from the Library and `~/.docker`, but upon reinstalling the app, my previous settings are still there (Starting Docker upon login is enabled, which is disabled by default). I have also restarted my computer multiple times and tried resetting to factory settings and uninstalling from the Troubleshoot menu, but to no avail.

What could I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that something is set in your *"defaults"* that is upsetting `docker`.

If I generate a list of all *"defaults"* domains on my Mac, and search for `docker`, I get the following:

```
defaults domains | tr ',' '\n' | grep -i docker
com.docker.docker
com.electron.dockerdesktop
```

So, if all else is lost, you might consider using the `defaults` command to delete those two domains and hope that docker starts with sensible defaults, or then re-install. I haven't tried this as my docker instance is working nicely.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, when running the command above, I get an empty response.